# GPU fan noisy after cleaning

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan, noise, cleaning

I have a PC with a Radeon 6450 video card. Some days ago I used canned air to clean the computer, I sprayed gently.

When I then tried to start the computer it went fine, up until after some 3 hours of casual internet browsing the GPU fan started to making a loud noise which would not end so I turned off the computer.
Then I started the computer again, the whole thing repeated itself after some 3 hours (not exact) of internet browsing.

Right now I could only use the computer for some 3 hours up until the noise, turn it off for some more hours before I could use it again. If I try to 
start the computer right after I turned it off, the sound/(sped up spining?) will be there, I have to wait hours before I can turn it on again. I wonder if this could be related to a overheating issue - That I have to wait before the fan have "gone back" to its regular spin/sound?

What could have happend when I cleaned the computer? I didnt sprayed directly at the fan/making it spin. 
Is it a ball-bearing the issue? (does my old video card have ball bearing?) Could dust have entered the ball-bearing and thus making the noise?
Could I somehow (how?) have damaged the video card sensor making the temperature sensor corrupt and therefore making the fan spin fast and loudly.
I dont know if the loud noise come from the fan really spinning abnormally or if the noise come from broken ball-bearings (if, Radeon 6450 have that that is).

Any help or ideas is much appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, just another good example of why you should NEVER use compressed air to spray components inside your computer.  There is not really such a thing as "gently" when the air is under compression and usually also very cold due to the propellant.  With everything turned off and static-grounded, you can sometimes use a vacuum, but a plain wipe and q-tips do a better, safer job if you have serious dust build-up.  What possessed you to use the compressed air in the first place?  Was the fan already failing?

Comment: I hadnt cleaned it for some years and I was dumb enough to clean it - the computer was running more than fine, canned air is recommended by alot of people, I have used it before and it didnt cause this mishap I am in now but perhaps there was something this time causing the canned air to corrupt...something. I would never dare using a vaccum cleaner in the computer and touching with wipes etc I def would not dare. But this is off topic to my quesiton.

Comment: Well, the risk with a vacuum (and I don't mean the kind that does your rugs) is static, so everything has to be correctly static-grounded.  But an appropriate wipe is fine for dust buildup, as long as it's not the soapy kind that will leave residue.  I've used alcohol wipes inside computers for literally ~30 years now with never an issue, and used Q-tips for cleaning fans for nearly that long.  But the bottom line is that if everything is fine, leave the dust alone as trying to clean the inside of the case can often cause more harm than good.

Comment: BTW, the flip side of my experience with wipes is the number of times (I cringe to think how many) that someone has used compressed air inside a computer case & come to me because they caused damage despite being "careful".  However, the fan that's making noise is hopefully replaceable, and I'd suggest avoiding continuing to run the system for a few hours repeatedly, as you may be causing thermal damage or degradation.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about replacing the fan but I am not sure I could find a fan to my quite old video card, do you happen to know if there are ball bearings in ati radeon hd 6450, here a picture of the fan: https://img2.parts-people.com/products/4KHPHa1.JPG

Comment: I don't know much about the details of the fan itself, but I do see that there are replacement fans easily available -- just search for "replacement fan ati radeon hd 6450" -- and they don't seem terribly expensive when compared to the cost of the card.  Rather than mucking around with it at this point & risking overheating, I'd suggest you just replace the fan directly.